# Function in then() promise resolver always fires even if primise fails

Tags: javascript, vue.js

when I click a button I fire a vuex action, this action returns an  axios promise from the vuex store, in my component I want to reset form fileds ONLY when the action success, however right now it resets form fileds ALWAYS, even if the promise fails ... I'm using then and catch for this puropse, having the resetForm method fire in the then resolve, sadly it always resets no matter what...

This is the code in my component:

```
const self = this;


        this.sendContactMail(payload)
        .then((response) => {
            //This always fires, even if promise fails
            self.resetData();
        }, 
        (error) => {

        });
```

My vuex action:

```
sendContactMail({ commit }, payload)
    {        
        commit('Loader/SET_LOADER', { status:1 }, { root: true });
        return axios.post('/api/contacts/send-contact-mail', payload)
        .then((response) => {
            commit('Loader/SET_LOADER', { status:2, response: response }, { root: true });
        }, 
        (error) => {
            commit('Loader/SET_LOADER', { status:3, errors: error }, { root: true });
        });
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you handle your errors you stop the error from being propagated back up the promise chain. If you want the error to continue going up even after you handle it, you have to re-throw it in your error handling logic like

```js
return axios.post("/api/contacts/send-contact-mail", payload).then(
  response => {
    commit("Loader/SET_LOADER", { status: 2, response: response }, { root: true );
  },
  error => {
    commit("Loader/SET_LOADER", { status: 3, errors: error }, { root: true });
    throw error;
  }
);
```